# How to get index of element in array in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

JSONata provides several functions to operate on array contents. However, I am at a loss to determine how to return the index of a found element (similar to the Array.indexOf function in JavaScript). I'm looking for something like:

```
$indexOf(Account.Order[OrderID="order103"])
or
Account.Order.indexOf(OrderID="order103")
or
Account.Order[OrderID="order103"].index
```

Comment: I have posted a proposed solution in the JSONata github issues that takes the form $indexOf(array, searchObject) to return the index if found, or -1 if not found or invalid parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Account.Order ~> $map(function($v, $i) { $v.OrderID = 'order103' ? $i })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could merge map's index:

```
Account.Order ~> $map(function($v, $i) {
  $merge([{'Index': $i}, $v])
})~>function($x){$x[OrderID="order103"].Index}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither proposed solution ensured a valid response if not found but adding the additional test seems to do what I'd expected:

```
($x:=Account.Order ~> $map(function($v, $i) { $v.OrderID = 'order101' ? $i });
$exists($x)?$x:-1)
```

will return -1

```
($x:=Account.Order ~> $map(function($v, $i) { $v.OrderID = 'order103' ? $i });
$exists($x)?$x:-1)
```

will return 0

```
($x:=Account.Order ~> $map(function($v, $i) { $v.OrderID = 'order104' ? $i });
$exists($x)?$x:-1)
```

will return 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Accout.Order.OrderId#$i["order103" in $].$i
```

This is a built in way so should be faster

Comment: While Account.Order.OrderID#$i["order103" in $].$i returns 0 Account.Order.OrderID#$i["order104" in $].$i also returns 0 but should be 1